# Shopware 6: How can I set storefront domain URL in Shopware docker container using CLI command

Tags: docker, containers, shopware6, storefront

I have a Shopware 6 docker container running on port 8080. I am installing and activating plugins using these commands.

```rb
docker cp $PLUGIN_NAME $SHOPWARE_CONTAINER_ID:/var/www/html/custom/plugins/

docker exec -it $SHOPWARE_CONTAINER_ID /bin/bash -c "cd /var/www/html && bin/console plugin:install --activate $PLUGIN_NAME"
```

By default, the domain URL of the storefront is `http://localhost/`. How can I configure Shopware to use `http://localhost:8080/` as the storefront domain URL using the CLI command?

Is there any way to do it using CLI command? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command `bin/console sales-channel:update:domain newdomain.com` will update the sales channel domain for every sales channel.

To only replace 1 specific domain with a new domain, you can use the 'previousDomain' option.

For you example, I would try the following command, if 'localhost' is the currently configured domain:

```
bin/console sales-channel:update:domain "localhost:8080" localhost
```

Comment: Thanks, actually I am running a test.sh script file. In which I have the commands I mentioned in the question. Would the command you gave, work in the script?